# How to set an external variable from Angular RxJS map method?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm attempting to convert some code to be reactive/declarative using the async pipe to update the template.  One of thing things I'm struggling with is setting a variable that was previously set in the subscribe() method.  Updating that variable instead from the map or tap method does not work ... I know I'm missing something obvious here, do I need to look at something like "subjects" and combining streams?

Previous Code:

```
result.subscribe(records => {
      this.generateChartData(records);
      this.loading = false;
    });
```

Updated Code:

```
    this.result$
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => {console.log("here")}),
        map((records) => {
          this.areStatsAvailable = true;
          this.loading = false;
          return this.generateChartDataStream(records);
        })
      );
```

It's the "loading" variable I'm trying to set which is used in the template.

Comment: Yes, `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` are better. First declare property `loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);` Then `loading$.next(false);` but better in another `tap` after `map`. And in the template `...*ngIf="loading$ | async"...`

Comment: in order to make that code execute (whatever you have in tap or map, etc..), somewhere in your code need to `subscribe`  to `this.result$`, otherwise, the logic within `pipe` won't execute or trigger...

Comment: Thx Benny, that seems exactly what I would need ... however it seems that the loading subject value isn't being reflected in the template for some reason.  I'm using the async pipe as you described and using the next method to update it.  Is there a good way to debug subjects?  I tried adding a tap to it with a console log to output the value but nothing is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example maybe can help u

```
   this.loading$ = this.result$.pipe(
   tap((res) => {
   this.areStatsAvailable = true;
   this.loading = false;
   }),
   map((records) => {
   return this.generateChartDataStream(records);
    })
   );
```

and in ur template it will like this :

```
<div *ngIf="(loading$ | async) as loading">Loading ....</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't think I can assign the loading$ to the result$ as that observable does not return a boolean stream.

Comment: i updated the reponse can u check?

Comment: I think that's closer ... however I'm trying to avoid using Subscribe() methods so the result$ observable is being subscribed instead in the template using the async pipe.  Is there a way to remove the subscribe to the result$ observable in your above example and achieve the same results?

Comment: check i updated it again

Comment: same as before, the result stream returns an array of data and loading stream is just a boolean observable value, so not sure how you can assign one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

See a simple example here: https://angular-yqwegd.stackblitz.io

And here is the code (**main.ts**):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <div *ngIf="loading$ | async">Loading...</div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of result$ | async">{{ item }}</div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  result$: Observable<number[]>;
  loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('waiting for back end...');
    this.result$ = of(null).pipe(
      delay(2000),
      map(() => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
      tap((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.loading$.next(false);
      })
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```